# How to add event listener for checkbox in Chrome extension's popup?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to capture changes of `checkbox` in popup of my Chrome Extension. Documentation [says](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/contentSecurityPolicy.html#H3-1):

> Inline JavaScript will not be executed

There is an example provided on the same page, but it for `button`. I don't know how to modify it so it would capture chekbox's state changes.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
});
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Had the same problem but reference a very helpful site which list events in Javascript.  After doing a quick search (Ctrl+F) for the keyword "check" I found the "change" event listed...supposedly compatible with most browsers.  Sure enought it was there, so my assumption is that maybe there is a "change event" for checkboxes.  Low and behold just test it and it seems to work.  Here is your code revised a little and the link of events (http://help.dottoro.com/larrqqck.php):

Example of html from popup.html

```
    <div class="menu" >
<input type="checkbox" id="showAlert" name="showAlert"/>
<label for="showAlert"><nobr>Show Alert</nobr></label></div>
```

Example of code snippet from popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      document.querySelector('#showAlert').addEventListener('change', changeHandler);
});
```

Of course you will need to pass this into a function like:

```
function changeHandler(){
   //Do Something...maybe another function showAlert(), for instance
   if(showAlert.checked){
      //do something
   }
   else{
      //do something else
   }
}
```

**01/06/2018 - EDIT:**
I just glanced back at this article and it appears this is likely going to become deprecated.  Hence forward you may wish to use the MutationObserver (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Comment: I would probably use this changeHandler: `function changeHandler(e){
        
       if(e.target.checked){
          alert("Checked");
       }
       else{
          alert("Not checked");
       }
    }`

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
document.querySelector('checkbox').addEventListener('CheckboxStateChange', Handler);
```

Alternatively, you can listen to the 'onChange' or 'onClick' events, since every click will change the status of the checkbox.

Comment: No, it's not working. And I can't find `CheckboxStateChange` event in [DOM event reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference).

Comment: @Roman Or you can use 'onChange' or 'onClick' instead. See the updated answer.

Comment: `CheckboxStateChange` is only supported by Firefox.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff Just to elaborate it seems to be an XUL event which soon won't even be supported by Firefox as they embrace chrome API extensions.